# How to write a one-page file to disk in one flush?

Tags: files, kernel, io

Say I have 4096 bytes of data that I want to save in a file. It should take exactly one page and can be flushed only once. However, if I do it using multiple calls to kernel i.e. write piece by piece, the kernel might interrupt my writing to flush the current content to the disk and then when I finish writing it would flush agian. So to make sure it doesn't waste its flushes I would have to make only one call to the kernel. That would be `write`. **Does using `write` once guarantee me that the page will be marked dirty only once?**

`man` pages offer some `MAP_UNINITIALIZED` that I could use together with `MAP_FIXED` to map some prewritten page to the file and then `msync` to write it to the file, but they say it's only available on embedded devices.

Kernel source code reveals that `write` translates to `sys_write` whish translates to `my_syscall3` which is a macro with assembler code that only fills some registers and writes a single line `"syscall\n"` I have no clue how to investigate the source code further to find the answer to my question.

EDIT: Now I see the misunderstanding. When I say flush, I (wrongly) don't really mean a flush. I mean a flush to kernel's cache. That place from where the kernel picks pages to flush. I.e. I want to mark the page as dirty only once. That is precisely what I want. I don't want to mark the page as dirty then kernel updates, sets the page as not dirty then I write more and mark it as dirty again. I want to `write` atomically. Is `write` atomic with respect to dirtying pages?

Comment: Can you describe what "atomic in terms of dirtying pages" would mean?

Comment: And again, what is the problem you're solving. It seems like you want to optimize away updates that are free.

Comment: That the state of durtyness doesn't change while `write` is operating. Specifically, that if I open,write(once),close then the state of dirtyness doesn'y change from clean to dirty twice.

Comment: How can something change from clean to dirty if it's dirty to begin with? And what would be the overhead here?

Comment: Because kernel could flush it in the middle of `write` and make it clean again.

Comment: Yeah but then it actually is clean and had been dirtied by your write. I don't understand what the problem here is. I thought this was not about disk -atomicity? What is the downside of marking a clean page dirty?

Comment: And you kernel will flush these pages out as pressure gets high enough, which is what you want it to do, to limit precariousness of uncommitted data

Comment: Linux has threads (i think they are called something like pflushers) that repeatedly check the state of pressure and write. If that thread can pause my write operation then after it flushed the half-dirty page to the disk (physically), my write will continue, marking the page as dirty. When I close the file descriptor, kernel is left to flush my (again) dirty page. On the next cycle of pflusher, my page will again be flushed to the disk. That is 2 flushes, while it could only be one.

Comment: If I did a memcpy or a loop that copies byte by byte then that cycle can surely be paused by the pflusher. But `write` is an in-kernel function so it maybe can't be paused.

Comment: I also don't understand why everyone here insists on "why I need something". If it's a valid, well-defined question, it has a valid, well-defined answer.

Comment: @MarcusMüller How can I ask the kernel developers about this?

Comment: I don't think you'll ask kernel developers about this. You don't have an actual problem - you just feel you have one. I'd you want to change the way the kernel works, describe what the problem is in hard numbers, a metric; make a really large, objective set of benchmarks to prove you have a problem, then change the kernel yourself (or pay someone to do it), and show that it significantly improves the metric you captured with your benchmark. Then argue compellingly that your solution actually is widely useful abd not just for your user case (would want to show other databases would benefit,too)

Comment: You'd then get in contact with the storage/VFS subsystem maintainers and prepare them that you have an intrusive change to the core architecture, and that you've done your due diligence, explain the problem that you're actually solving and convince them with your benchmarks and the quality of your code.

Comment: **But** you still don't have anything to solve. You actually just think that these things should be one flush, where in reality the desire to write it data soon will be needed to be balanced with the desire to cache everything for as long as possible. And you've really not shown any attempt at clarifying why that trade-off wouldn't work for you, even after being repeatedly told that you cannot influence it from user land

Comment: I really don't think you're a moron – I wouldn't discuss with one. Sorry I came across unbearably. Please understand that I'd really like to encourage you to put the problem you're having into hard numbers to know how you can solve it – you came up with an approach, namely doing your own applicaton-side write buffering, and it would really make sense to investigate how much that increases these numbers. I think we've come to an understanding that I've explained why you cannot stop the kernel from doing flushes through write (no matter whether you agree with the statement), and assuming I was

Comment: correct about that, you'd want to figure out what the alternatives to the approach you hoped for would be. But for evaluation of alternatives, you need something you can compare, hence my effort to push you into quantifying the problem instead of proposing and discussing a solution before that. Again, my apologies for upsetting you – I didn't mean to.

Answer (score 0):

same man page:

> A  successful return from write() does not make any guarantee that data has been committed to disk.

There's not necessarily be any one flush, and as a userland process you also can't know the necessities of the storage system (512 B blocks on a hard drive, written consecutively to a file but due to fragmentations to different ends of the disk? Network file system with a timeout? LVM duplicated across 256 disks?) to make assessments on how many physical interactions with the storage medium will be necessary to commit the written data to storage.

The only thing that is guaranteed is that if your file system makes POSIX guarantees (so, any of the "UNIXy" file systems like XFS, NFS, …), then the moment `write` returns, the data just written must be visible to reads after.

---

Without knowing the reason you ask:
I'm also not quite sure why you'd worry about avoiding flushes – filesystems, unless specifically told not to, will cache and not flush data to disk all the time, but in efficient bulks. So, it's fairly probable that neither your 4 KB nor smaller writes would instantly kick off a write, unless the medium is active but idling away, anyways.

Comment: When I said "in one flush" I was constraining the ambient to my file and one disk. If it's ever written to the disk then there has been at least one flush. I am asking about guarantee that it is not more than 1 flush. Agian, I am not going into specificities of different filesystems and different hardware. I am concerned only about abstract communication with the kernel. All that the kernel can tell is whether my page is dirty or not. I am essentially asking whether a page can become dirty while `write` call is still operating, or only after the call has returned. Also,...

Comment: Also, the man page doesn't enlist regular files under examples of when `write` can return less than requested bytes: "The number of bytes written may be less than count if, for example, there is insufficient space on the underlying physical medium, or the RLIMIT_FSIZE resource limit is encountered (see setr-limit(2)), or the call was interrupted by a signal handler after having written less than count bytes. (See also pipe(7).)" The file is being rewritten so there is surely enough free space and 4096 is certainly less than RLIMIT_FSIZE. I can also not handle any signals on my thread.

Comment: I am not using direct IO, so how the kernel flushes is not up to me, I only want to only once mark the page as dirty and let the kernel flush it however it thinks is the best. That part should be up to me.

Comment: As said, no such guarantee about any specific number of flushes. If you want the kernel to just commit data to disk at is own discretion: just use one or multiple write, that's what the kernel does anyway. But you seem to be attributing special properties to your page size, which I don't seem to be able to recognize.

Comment: Let me ask again: what is the actual problem you think you can solve could you interfere directly with the write caching from userland and stop flushing of pages? What's the advantage?

Comment: I want to make a server program that is distributed with every client. There goes my control over hardware. The server shall maintain some huge database. Because it is not centralized it may happen that all clients shut down, so I need disk. If a client experiences a system crash, all unflushed data is lost (locally, but globally if it was the only online client). So I need often flushes. If I flush too often, I might damage the disk. So I need to control and limit the number of dirty pages. Luckily I can predict how often files will change and can flush them efficiently. That's why I need it.

Comment: You're not control of how rarely you flush. You can only explicitly force a fsync. End of story. But really, none of what you describe necessitates that kind of control.

Comment: I actually am in the control of how rarely flushes happen, because I can simply not link my VM page to the file. I can do changes privately and then copy them to a shared map of a file. My question is about that copying. If I copy using one write call, is it atomic?

Comment: No. I've written that multiple times now. It's also not a problem, no matter how you insist it is.

Comment: Your "no" refers to my question and I have already accepted your answer, I was just _answering you_, explaining what is the problem "I think I can solve if I were in the control"

Comment: Large database systems (also such that allow for "shards", which is what you'd call your "clients" in a database context) like PostgreSQL work reliably without being able to control these low level aspects

Comment: I want both reliability and efficiency. Flushing arbitrarliy often is not a solution.

Comment: Thank you for "shards", I haven't known of that term before!

Comment: Please tell that to PostgreSQL, they must have a bug if that's not an option ;) I honestly don't see the reliability problem you're solving here. If you don't know your underlying storage, how could you guarantee a one page write is atomic from the point of view of the disk, which has no notion of your page?

Comment: Well if there is no (found) counter-example to the statement it doesn't mean it's true. Maybe PostgreSQL really could be more efficient.

Comment: Sigh. I give up!

Comment: Well my question is not from the POV of the disk. Read my EDIT to the question.